# SQL Server episode identification

Tags: sql, sql-server, threshold

I am working with a blood pressure database in SQL Server which contains `patient_id`, `timestamp` (per minute) and `systolicBloodPressure`.

My goals are to find:

1. the number of episodes in which a patient is under a certain blood pressure threshold

   An episode consists of the timestmap where the patient drops below a certain threshold until the timestamp where the patient comes above the threshold.
2. the mean blood pressure per episode per patient
3. the duration of the episode per episode per patient

What I have tried so far:

I am able to identify episodes by just making a new column which sets to 1 if threshold is reached.

```
    select *
    , CASE
    when sys < threshold THEN '1'
    from BPDATA
```

However , I am not able to 'identify' different episodes within the patient; episode1 episode 2 with their relative timestamps.

Could someone help me with this? Or is there someone with a better different solution?

EDIT: Sample data with example threshold 100

```
    ID          Timestamp      SysBP      below Threshold
    ----------------------------------------------------
    1             9:38          110       Null
    1             9:39          105       Null
    1             9:40          96        1
    1             9:41          92        1 
    1             9:42          102       Null
    2             12:23         95        1
    2             12:24         98        1
    2             12:25         102       Null
    2             12:26         104       Null
    2             12:27         94        1
    2             12:28         88        1  
    2             12:29         104       Null
```

Comment: I would suggest that you delete this question.  Then ask another question about the first item, along with sample data and desired results.  As written, this is rather broad for a single "question".

Comment: I don't think it's too broad, it's probably all a single query. No need to be creating a new question, but you should definitely provide the schema, sample data etc.

Comment: I included sample data. Please do not hesitate to ask if you need more information!

Comment: It looks like `gaps-and-islands`. The best query depends on the version of your SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the sample data.

This should work:

```
declare @t table (ID int, Timestamp time, SysBP int, belowThreshold bit)
insert @t 
values
(1,              '9:38',          110, null),
(1,              '9:39',          105, null),
(1,              '9:40',           96, 1),
(1,              '9:41',           92, 1),
(1,              '9:42',          102, null),
(2,             '12:23',           95, 1),
(2,             '12:24',           98, 1),
(2,             '12:25',          102, null),
(2,             '12:26',          104, null),
(2,             '12:27',           94, 1),
(2,             '12:28',           88, 1),
(2,             '12:29',          104, null)

declare @treshold int = 100

;with y as (
    select *, case when lag(belowThreshold, 1, 0) over(partition by id order by timestamp) = belowThreshold then 0 else 1 end epg
    from @t
),
z as (
    select *, sum(epg) over(partition by id order by timestamp) episode
    from y
    where sysbp < @treshold
)
select id, episode, count(episode) over(partition by id) number_of_episodes_per_id, avg(sysbp) avg_sysbp, datediff(minute, min(timestamp), max(timestamp))+1 episode_duration
from z
group by id, episode
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it seems to work with the sample data. However, I just started working with SQL and am not able to get it to work with my own Table. Could you add some comments to your code about you have done? and give some advice how to implement te code with by own table?

Comment: Based on what you posted, that's all I can do. Pls add some more relevant and closer to reality schema and data.

Comment: It works great but there is still one tiny problem. I would like to have in the 'episode collumn' the episode number **per person**. At the moment person1 has episode **1** and person 2 has episodes **2 & 3** while I want person 2 to have episodes starting again by 1, so **1 and 2**.

Answer (score 0):

This answer relies on LEAD() and LAG() functions so only works on 2012 or later:

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE #bloodpressure 
(
    Patient_id int,
    [TimeStamp] SmallDateTime,
    SystolicBloodPressure INT
)

INSERT INTO #bloodpressure
VALUES
(1, '2017-01-01 09:01', 60),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:02', 55),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:03', 60),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:04', 70),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:05', 72),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:06', 75),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:07', 60),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:08', 50),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:09', 52),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:10', 53),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:11', 65),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:12', 71),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:13', 73),
(1, '2017-01-01 09:14', 74),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:01', 70),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:02', 75),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:03', 80),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:04', 70),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:05', 72),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:06', 75),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:07', 60),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:08', 50),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:09', 52),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:10', 53),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:11', 65),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:12', 71),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:13', 73),
(2, '2017-01-01 09:14', 74),
(3, '2017-01-01 09:12', 71),
(3, '2017-01-01 09:13', 60),
(3, '2017-01-01 09:14', 74)
```

Now using Lead And Lag to find the previous rows values, to find whether this is the beginning or end of a sequence of low blood pressures, in combination with a common table expression. Using a UNION of start and end events ensures that an event which covers just one minute is recorded as both a start and an end event.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *, 
        LAG(SystolicBloodPressure,1) 
            OVER (PaRTITION BY Patient_Id ORDER BY TimeStamp) As PrevValue, 
        Lead(SystolicBloodPressure,1) 
            OVER (PaRTITION BY Patient_Id ORDER BY TimeStamp) As NextValue  
    FROM #bloodpressure
),
CTE2
AS
(
    -- Get Start Events (EventType 1)
    SELECT 1 As [EventType],  Patient_id, TimeStamp,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Patient_id, TimeStamp) AS RN
    FROM CTE
    WHERE (PrevValue IS NULL AND SystolicBloodPressure < 70) OR 
          (PrevValue >= 70 AND SystolicBloodPressure < 70)
    UNION
    -- Get End Events (EventType 2)
    SELECT 2 As [EventType],  Patient_id, TimeStamp, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Patient_id, TimeStamp) AS RN
    FROM CTE
    WHERE (NextValue IS NULL AND SystolicBloodPressure < 70 ) OR 
          (NextValue >= 70 AND SystolicBloodPressure < 70)
)
SELECT C1.Patient_id, C1.TimeStamp As EventStart, C2.TimeStamp As EventEnd 
FROM CTE2 C1
INNER JOIN CTE2 C2
    ON C1.Patient_id = C2.Patient_id AND C1.RN = C2.RN
WHERE C1.EventType = 1 AND C2.EventType = 2
ORDER BY C1.Patient_id, C1.TimeStamp
```